# How to float window alway in left in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

When user moving window and placing in another position then window place always in left. how to possible this. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**LocationChanged** Event may do the work.

- prepare the location where you want to see your window on screen.
- create LocationChanged event.
- check new location with your prepared location
- if location changed , then re locate your window to prepared location.

Comment: LocationChanged event firing frequently or just when we moving window. show how to work this event.